# What's the difference between string.function() or function(string) in C++?

Tags: c++

In some cases in c++ we use entities as string.length() but sometimes we use them as reverse(string.begin, string.end). 
What's the difference between the two?
How can I determine when to use which form?

Comment: `std::string` is not a "primitive" as one colloquially means

Comment: True. I edited the question.

Comment: Well, `a.b()` calls the `b` member function of the object `a`. `b(a)` calls some function `b` that takes `a` as an argument. I'm not the best at explaining stuff...

Comment: @FeiXiang. You did a pretty good job this time...

Comment: I guess an analogy might be that `aCar.unlockDoor()` is like telling a car to unlock the door (asking a string to tell you it's length), and `destroy(car)` is like giving `car` to some machine that destroys it (giving a string to a function that reverses stuff).

Comment: Function vs  method. Nothing to say more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we define:

```
std::string string; 

string.length(); // is calling the length method/member function of the string object.
```

which is http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size

On the other hand,

```
reverse(string.begin(), string.end());
```

is calling a free function(not a method/member function) defined in the STL algorithm library(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse), thus we cannot do `string.reverse(...)`

A method should be called on an object. A free function should be called without an object.

By the way, `string` is not a primitive type(it's a class defined in `<string>`). Primitive types(`int`, `double`, `char`...) don't have any methods.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I determine when to use which form?

Whatever fits your needs best. Technically there is no downside either using e.g. `std::string::find` or `std::find`. While member functions like `std::string::find` might offer easier usage for their container type, they are limited to only this very container type (e.g. `std::string`):

The motivation of the [algorithm library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) (e.g. where `std::reverse` belongs to) is to give the user one interface which works with [different containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) like `std::string`, `std::vector`, `std::map` etc. This is achieved by using [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) which every container has.